# How to fix the error when trying to access the API?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, postman, localhost

I want to generate token to do the CRUD operations in SharePoint Online list. I am able to generate the token in Postman. But I want that it automatically gets generated in my React app to do the CRUD operations. I copied the code snippet from the Postman and pasted in my React app, but it is throwing error. Here is the error :

```
UsingFetch.js:181          POST https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/834fb7b4-624d-4de8-a977-2d46ad979bd9/tokens/OAuth/2 400 (Bad Request)

{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.\r\nTrace ID: d2dcb2da-1aae-4af2-a3e3-aabc35ce4301\r\nCorrelation ID: c90dff14-b64d-4f47-a01c-dfe498ec2f40\r\nTimestamp: 2022-02-23 09:07:45Z","error_codes":[900144],"timestamp":"2022-02-23 09:07:45Z","trace_id":"d2dcb2da-1aae-4af2-a3e3-aabc35ce4301","correlation_id":"c90dff14-b64d-4f47-a01c-dfe498ec2f40","error_uri":"https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/error?code=900144"}
```

Here is the screenshot of the [image: Error]

Here is the code snippet that I copied from Postman :

```
const generateToken = async () => {
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    myHeaders.append(
      "Cookie",
      "esctx=AQABAAAAAAD--DLA3VO7QrddgJg7WevrQx7IG43UK7gipYHXtqZImLB1jfBLK4PTkZlgLq3BvpTizt3xt8EZQrpUJGa0hTnSdpRf-AenJvnGNABiv2cWYWSyJj9QNm-vWalRGHuDZ6Km_DaX_5CQHUa4H8U-osEGCM48buOyj0G819e1NoxuvoOD6fZvMI5nnDWZyjNa1mogAA; fpc=An1vbDtRI8BAiCLlUBBGpFXf9_srAQAAACDgp9kOAAAA; stsservicecookie=estsfd; x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd"
    );

    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
    formdata.append(
      "client_id",
      "myclientid"
    );
    formdata.append(
      "client_secret",
      "mysecretcode"
    );
    formdata.append(
      "resource",
      "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000/cooponline.sharepoint.com@834fb7b4-624d-4de8-a977-2d46ad979bd9"
    );

    var requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: formdata,
      redirect: "follow",
    };

    await fetch(
      "https://accounts.accesscontrol.windows.net/834fb7b4-624d-4de8-a977-2d46ad979bd9/tokens/OAuth/2",
      requestOptions
    )
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((result) => console.log(result))
      .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
  };
```

Can anyone please provide me with a solution?
Thank you.

Comment: btw, NEVER ever post your `client_id` or `client_secret` publicly. I won't check if they are valid in this case, but I highly recommend you omit them from this snippet, or anyone will have full access to this resource. Also, since they are public now, you should renew your secret entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error says what's wrong: `The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'`.

To fix this, just add it as a parameter (`formData` in this case). According to the [SharePoint docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token), this value must be set to `client_credentials`.

```js
formdata.append(
    "grant_type",
    "client_credentials"
);
```

**EDIT**:

Apparently, the request body has an unusual format. You're trying to send it as `application/json`, but MS expects `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` like this:

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1           //Line breaks for clarity
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default
&client_secret=sampleCredentia1s
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

So, instead of passing `formData` object as the request body, you should wrap it into a string like this:

```
const body = Object.keys(formData)
    .map(key => `${key}=${formData[key]}`)
    .join('&');
```

and pass that as the body.

Comment: Thank you for the advice that you gave me regarding client id and client secret.
Also regarding the fix, I have already added that in the code. Please have a look at my code snippet.

Comment: No, the problem still persists. I am still facing the same error.

Comment: @AnxiousMaster I just went through their docs again and (probably) found the solution. Take a look at my edited answer.